# DateTime.Now não Atualiza se a hora mudar

Tags: c#, vb.net

Tenho em aplicação com um timer em execução, tendo um interval de 1000ms. Esse timer faz algumas rotinas a cada X tempo, e dentre estas rotinas a hora do cliente é muito importante. já percebemos que em alguns casos a hora do cliente que aparece no relógio no canto da tela está certo, mas na aplicação vem com uma hora a menos pelo fato do fuso horário dele estar errado.

Feito os ajustes no S.O. do cliente, a minha aplicação ainda continua capturando a data/hora errada(com o fuso horário errado).

linha de código que estou usando:

```
 Dim horariostatus As String = Format(System.DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd")
 horariostatus &= " " & Format(System.DateTime.UtcNow, "HH:mm:ss")
```

OBS: Sim, eu estou armazenando em uma String por depois esta informação tem algumas tratativas antes de enviar para nosso servidor;

Comment: a sua aplicação é executada no cliente?

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, a aplicação é executada no cliente;

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim current As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.Local //Pega Time Zone do Local da Execução do programa
 Dim horaDestino As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time") //Selecionamos a região da data e hora que desejamos gravar
 Dim horaAtual As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(current.Id) //Selecona o Time Zone para fazer a alteração
 Dim horaConvertida as DateTime //Variável que vai receber a data e a hora convertida

 horaConvertida = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, horaAtual, horaDestino) //Converte para o horário do servidor aqui no caso como horário de Brasília
```